# Debian 12 - Suspend sometimes doesn't work

Tags: debian, systemd, suspend

After installing Debian 12 on my laptop, suspend sometimes doesn't work. Trying from the shutdown menu in Gnome, or by using `systemctl suspend`, I encounter the same random behavior. I can't figure out the reason, and the further I've reached is to this `dmesg` output:

```
...
[  920.574290] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 72:be:dd:c2:bf:37 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  922.410249] PM: suspend entry (deep)
[  922.433848] Filesystems sync: 0.023 seconds
[  922.434122] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin
[  922.434244] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db
[  922.434247] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db.p7s
[  922.434677] Freezing user space processes
[  922.627265] Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.192 seconds)
[  922.627287] OOM killer disabled.
[  922.627293] Freezing remaining freezable tasks
[  922.628995] Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
[  922.629111] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  922.645882] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  922.645960] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  922.646480] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[  922.656194] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[  922.856410] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[  922.890083] ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[  922.891676] ACPI: EC: event blocked
[  922.891679] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
[  922.891681] ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[  922.891837] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[  922.891840] Wakeup pending. Abort CPU freeze
[  922.891841] Non-boot CPUs are not disabled
[  922.891844] ACPI: EC: EC started
[  922.891903] ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[  922.916784] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[  922.929087] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
[  922.929349] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
[  923.096339] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
[  923.230005] pci 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller
[  923.230146] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:02:00.0
[  923.231664] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[  923.233768] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x43
[  923.241795] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
[  923.241806] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[  923.557066] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[  923.560549] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  923.561026] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[  923.561722] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  924.653491] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
[  924.655999] OOM killer enabled.
[  924.656010] Restarting tasks ... done.
[  924.661652] random: crng reseeded on system resumption
[  924.671958] PM: suspend exit
[  924.672021] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[  924.680832] Filesystems sync: 0.008 seconds
[  924.681081] Freezing user space processes
[  924.898848] Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.217 seconds)
[  924.898869] OOM killer disabled.
[  924.898875] Freezing remaining freezable tasks
[  924.900593] Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
[  924.900611] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  924.925931] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  924.925936] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  924.926453] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[  924.936083] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[  925.217919] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[  925.218401] intel_pch_thermal 0000:00:14.2: CPU-PCH is cool [40C]
[  925.251115] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[  925.262135] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
[  925.262285] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
[  925.432103] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
[  925.566027] pci 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller
[  925.566112] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:02:00.0
[  925.567311] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x43
[  925.577396] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[  925.577743] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
[  925.893542] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[  925.893588] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[  925.894490] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  925.897577] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  927.007120] OOM killer enabled.
[  927.007130] Restarting tasks ... 
[  927.007161] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
[  927.016812] done.
[  927.016826] random: crng reseeded on system resumption
[  927.030961] PM: suspend exit
[  927.155300] RTL8208 Fast Ethernet r8169-0-202:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-202:00, irq=MAC)
[  927.295042] r8169 0000:02:00.2 enp2s0f2: Link is Down
[  928.438619] wlp3s0: authenticate with 72:be:dd:c2:bf:37
[  928.438643] wlp3s0: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
[  928.451658] wlp3s0: send auth to 72:be:dd:c2:bf:37 (try 1/3)
[  928.453781] wlp3s0: authenticated
[  928.457789] wlp3s0: associate with 72:be:dd:c2:bf:37 (try 1/3)
[  928.473486] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 72:be:dd:c2:bf:37 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=2)
[  928.473658] wlp3s0: associated
[  928.473848] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[  928.473853] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[  928.473855] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[  928.473858] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[  928.473861] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[  928.473863] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[  928.473866] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country element
[  928.504418] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 72:be:dd:c2:bf:37
[  928.562192] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
...
```

The most concerning `dmesg` output lines for me are these:

```
[  922.856410] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[  922.890083] ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[  922.891676] ACPI: EC: event blocked
[  922.891679] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
[  922.891681] ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[  922.891837] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[  922.891840] Wakeup pending. Abort CPU freeze
[  922.891841] Non-boot CPUs are not disabled
[  922.891844] ACPI: EC: EC started
[  922.891903] ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[  922.916784] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
```

So I think there would be a problem with the CPU not being able to enter the suspend state.

This is my `inxi -b` output:

```
System:
  Host: debian Kernel: 6.1.0-10-amd64 arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME v: 43.6 Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: X541UJ v: 1.0
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: X541UJ v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends v: X541UJ.310 date: 04/18/2019
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 8.7 Wh (100.0%) condition: 8.7/23.8 Wh (36.5%)
    volts: 10.8 min: 10.8
CPU:
  Info: dual core Intel Core i7-7500U [MT MCP] speed (MHz): avg: 1850
    min/max: 400/3500
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 620 driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GK208BM [GeForce 920M] driver: N/A
  Device-3: Chicony USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.9 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915
    resolution: 1366x768~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 22.3.6 renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 620 (KBL
    GT2)
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet driver: r8169
  Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
    driver: ath9k
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.13 TiB used: 6.78 GiB (0.6%)
Info:
  Processes: 283 Uptime: 2m Memory: 15.5 GiB used: 1.69 GiB (10.9%)
  Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.26
```

As a side note, I've tried to reinstall Debian 12 Bookworm using the Debian 11 Bullseye netinstall, and update to 12 from there. This way, I've been able to keep the Bullseye kernel (5.10 series) and I can boot Bookworm from it. The suspend feature works fine on the older kernel.

Anyone has experienced something similar and tried to solve it?

Comment: I've had this, but can't help much. A detail to add: the suspend seemed to be partial. The leds and the fan were on, but the system gui seemed suspended. Pressing the power button (set for suspension) a few times shortly after the suspension start seemed to help.